# font faces in firefox 26-31

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

Looks like firefox have a troubles in understanding what i want from him. Chrome understands me very well.But firefox is declines to understand that want "normal" fonts when i write (font-face:normal) to a property.It makes my block "ligter" like font in parent block.WHY!?!?!?

```
@font-face{
    font-family:Myriad;
    src:url('../fonts/MyriadPro-R.ttf');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Myriad;
    src:url('../fonts/MyriadPro-B.ttf');
    font-weight:bold;
     font-style:normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:Myriad;
    src:url('../fonts/MyriadPro-L.ttf');
    font-weight:lighter;
     font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a free Web fonts? Loading a **licensed** Myriad Pro font doesn't look right. From CSS specification, `normal` = 400. Does the loaded font has font weight 400 ? Also, it is a very bad practice to use only 1 font in `font-family` (without providing fallback); add at least 1 fallback font, especially you are using custom font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to use the numerical weights of the font faces i.e font-weight:200 etc since each browser renders fonts differently, therefore you will see a bigger difference when loading bold/lighter as compared to 600/400 etc.

Find out which weights each fonts supports and use the numerical value.

Change the font family names to represent the different font weights eg Myriad Light, Myriad Bold, Myriad for more readable css and less confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The value `lighter` is invalid for the [`font-weight` property inside a `@font-face` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop-desc) (as the W3C CSS Validator would tell you). Use a numeric weight instead. The proper value should be found in the information provided by the font vendor.